# Tool tip is not showing on the appropriate nob

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

i'm having issues in my UI, which the Tool Tip not displying in appropriate nob after i scroll down.

```
<div ng-init="hideTooltip[$index]=1" ng-click="toggleTooltip($index, $event);" style="float:right;margin-top:7px" class="menu-toggle-black" ng-show="hideTooltip[$index]==1&&isNotAdmin(permission)"> 
    <ul class="menu-tooltip margin-left-140px" ng-show="showTooltip[$index] == 1">
        <li ng-apply-privilege="VRM_ADD_PERMISSIONS" class="logout" ng-click="editButton($index, permission);"><span><a translate="usermanagement.view.EDIT"></a></span></li>
        <li ng-apply-privilege="VRM_DELETE_PERMISSIONS" class="logout" ng-click="deleteButton($index);"><span><a translate="usermanagement.view.DELETE"></a></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
    .menu-tooltip{position:fixed;}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not able to add an image here, it asks 10 reputation to post an image. What can i do now. if i add an image it will be helpful to get clear vision of the error

Comment: A link to a live example is better than an image.  JSFiddle and CodePen are the best.  But if I had to guess, the tooltip is positioned using "fixed" positioning.  When you scroll, it's not going to move unless you move it manually.

Comment: If I'm not using position fixed, the tool tip is displaying behind the Ui screen. if I'm using position fixed it displaying in front of the screen. but i'm getting the error only in corner case that after scroll down the scroll bar

Comment: A better solution is to keep the fixed positioning and reposition it during scroll.  Attach a scroll event to the window and move the tooltip as the user scrolls.

Comment: can u please provide me that code? i'm new to this

Comment: #Ryanwheale pls help to solve  that

Comment: Hi any one can help me out from this error

Comment: You are building an app using angular.  You should be able to attach to the scroll event and do some basic math.  If not, you're in way above your head.  Make an attempt to figure it out on your own, and come back here for help.  Otherwise hire a guy to do it for you if you don't feel like trying to figure it out on your own (not trying to be a dick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set tooltip position fixed, it would not move when page scroll,

You should set container position relative, and tolltip position absolute.

Something like below

```
.menu-toggle-black {
    position:relative;
 }
 .menu-tooltip{
   position:absolute;
   top:0; /* or positive or negative value you need.*/
   left:100%; /* or positive or negative value you need.*/
  }
```

Comment: if i'm using    position:absolute    the tool tip is not dispaying in the nob.